# Java send Personalized Object by socket

Tags: java, object, server, send

my problem is about java send personalized object, 
i create a class Rilevazione, than i want to send a object Rilevazione to a client that read the object and  print it. 
here the server:

```
 try 
        {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);

            while (true) 
            {    
                // Create the Client Socket
                Socket client = welcomeSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Socket Extablished...");
                // Create input and output streams to client
                ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

                Rilevazione rl=new Rilevazione();
                outToClient.writeObject(rl);        

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Server Error: " + e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Localized: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.err.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
            System.err.println("To String: " + e.toString());
        }
```

Here the client:

```
try 
    {

            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(HOST, 50000);
            // Create the input & output streams to the server
            ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            Rilevazione rl=(Rilevazione)inFromServer.readObject();
            inFromServer.close();
            clientSocket.close();          

            rl.printit();




    }
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Client Error: " + e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Localized: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.err.println("Stack Trace: " + e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

the java compiler give me an error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            Rilevazione rl=(Rilevazione)inFromServer.readObject();
                            ^
```

why?
can anyone help me?
does the object must be serialized and than deserialized?

ps: the file strutture :
src >performancethinclient->- files.class

Comment: The class Rilevazione is in the second application classpath? Could you post the commands that you are using to compile and run?

Comment: Rilevazione is a simple class in the same package that define the object

Comment: to comple the application i use javac  from terminal

Comment: Try it: Just go to the. Java folder where they are located and usr javac  - cp .  *.java if it doesn't work,  could you post the folder structure?

Comment: it compile with :

Comment: javac - cp . *.java but when i lunch  the program with java it return these errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PerformanceThinClient (wrong name:

Comment: performancethinclient/PerformanceThinClient)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Comment: at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at

Comment: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Comment: Man,  dont comment the stacktrace... Edit your question with it,  its better...

Comment: Go one folder up and run with the package name... java - cp . performancethinclient.PerformanceThinClient

Comment: Did you saw my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told me,  if the classes all are in the same package you can compile with the following command:

```
javac -cp . *.java
```

To run your application go to the root folder and run the following:

```
java -cp . performancethinclient.PerformanceThinClient
```

Comment: Formnthe root of the source file ... Where there are the .classe file

Comment: run the command one folder up the package: e.g: if your source folder is src/performancethinclient, the you should run the java on src folder

Comment: I try ... It returns that is impossible to find the main class performancethinclient ...

Comment: Please, edit your original question with your folder structure and where your .class are located

Comment: On src folder run java -cp . performancethinclient.PerformanceThinClient

Comment: It complie and it runs but it doesn t do anything ....connection reset...

Comment: Ok, so the answer for your question is here...I helped you to compile and run the program, rigth? Now if theres is another problem with open/send the object through socket, please,  mark this answer with approved and open another question. There we start again and I can help you with sockets.

Comment: Soon i wilk post another question about that ... I Hope you could help me ... Thanks for your advice

Comment: Dont forget to accept my answer if it really helped you! I will look for your new question soon too!!